# Today date is highlighted in datepicker if data exist and changed automatically today date in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have HTML table and it contains datepicker column.
I write coding in js section to create datepicker.
I fill that columns data from DB.
It shows calendar successfully.

My problem : Get the date data from DB and show in table. It's Ok.
When I click to update, today date is highlighted and I didn't change nothing(just click) and move next field, Today date is set.

My Question: I want to show the date from DB when click datepicker.

```html
<input type="text" name="date_from[]" id="date_from" value="{{old('date_from[]',$sys_list->date_from)}}" size="9" autocomplete="off">
```

```js
$(function() {
        $('#sys_table').find('input[id^=date_from]').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'yyyymmdd',
            language: 'ja',
            orientation: 'bottom',
        });
```

Comment: what does `input`  value contain? post the rendered HTML using view page source

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple in `jQuery`,

```
$( '#sys_table').find( 'input[id^=date_from]' ).datepicker( {
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyymmdd',
    language: 'ja',
    orientation: 'bottom',
    defaultDate: '20191019'
} );
```

Make sure you enter the date in the string and in the exact format specified ie, in your case 'yyyymmdd'

TO capture data from the table,
Table: 1>20191010, 2>20191011, 3>20191012 ...
And you want to capture 20191010 when you click 1,
For this, assign a class to all the td in the first column(1,2,3...)
Then make a jquery function for that class,

```
$('.CLASSNAME').on('click',function(){
    data = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)).text();
});
```

data will give the date content, then do whatever you want to do with it!

Comment: Thanks verma, I tried defaultDate: '20191019' but, It didn't work. for example, my textfield has data '99999999' and I click it and close, it was changed to today date. Just click.

Comment: Ofcourse that will happen, because you are not entering a valid date, try to enter a valid date.

Comment: sorry, I tried with '20191019', but it was changed to today date. It occurs in first time, from second time it does not change.

Comment: Replace defaultDate by setDate, and if that doesn't work, replace setDate by 'setDate' (with quotes)

Comment: I have DB and get data and show as table. 1> 20190101 2>20190202 3>20190303.......... I want to show 20190101  when I click 1.......